# ERROR: BUILD:10:1: //:greeter: no such attribute 'src' in 'java_library' rule

Tags: java, compiler-errors, compilation, bazel

Got the following exception when compiling a Java project via Bazel.

```
BUILD:10:1: //:greeter: no such attribute 'src' in 'java_library' rule
```

*BUILD* file:

```
load("@rules_java//java:defs.bzl", "java_binary")

java_binary(
        name="ProjectRunner",
        srcs = ["src/main/java/com/example/ProjectRunner.java"],
        main_class = "com.example.ProjectRunner",
        deps = [":greeter"],
)

java_library(
        name="greeter",
        src=["src/main/java/com/example/Greeting.java"],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact that the attribute name in the java_library rule in the BULID file is: srcs not src.

```
load("@rules_java//java:defs.bzl", "java_binary")

java_binary(
        name="ProjectRunner",
        srcs = ["src/main/java/com/example/ProjectRunner.java"],
        main_class = "com.example.ProjectRunner",
        deps = [":greeter"],
)

java_library(
        name="greeter",
        **srcs**=["src/main/java/com/example/Greeting.java"],
)
```

Compiled and now running.

```
INFO: Analyzed target //:ProjectRunner (1 packages loaded, 4 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:ProjectRunner up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/ProjectRunner.jar
  bazel-bin/ProjectRunner
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.079s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
```